# How can I navigate from StackLayout DataTemplateSelector View?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have 1 stacklayout which contains data template selector. I use BindableLayout for it.
Now each child view inside stacklayout has separate viewmodel.
From that ViewModel I want to navigate to some other screen.

I have following code in my data template selector

```
var pageViewModel = (SomeViewModel)container.BindingContext;
if (view == Type.A)
{
  widgetView = new AView();
  widgetViewModel = pageViewModel.ServiceProvider.GetService<AViewModel>();
}
else
{
  widgetView = new BView();
  widgetViewModel = pageViewModel.ServiceProvider.GetService<BViewModel>();
}
widgetView.ViewModel = widgetViewModel;

var navigationParams = new NavigationParameters
                {
                    { Item, item }
                };
            widgetViewModel.LoadData(navigationParams);

            return new DataTemplate(() => widgetView);
```

From CustomView's ViewModel I'm trying to do

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("PageC");
```

I'm getting NavigationService object, but app is not navigation to **PageC**
If I call above same line in PageViewModel then app is redirecting to **PageC**

Comment: I'd use MessagingCenter to send a message from your VM to your page requesting that it perform navigation

Comment: How did you get this NavigationService in custom view?

Comment: I automatically get it, may be because I registered ViewModel like this.
registry.Register<AViewModel>();

Comment: @Jason Any way apart from MessagingCenter ? Can we use something like protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator() in App.Xaml.cs to modify NavigationService parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Implement ICommand property in your view models with predefined actions:

```
public ICommand Command { get; set; }
```

And bind it to whatever control you use for navigation event in you custom views.

IF you do it all in code you must somehow pass PageViewModel PRISM NavigationService instance to the custom view model also.

```
var navigationParams = new NavigationParameters
{
    { Item, item },
    { NavigationService, pageNavigationService)
};
```

without acctual code i can't tell exatcly how.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I know ICommand, but problem is I have to navigate from my Control's ViewModel.

Comment: @SagarPanwala i understand the question, I use that kind of navigation from DataLayout very often.